# Unable to get complex properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4

I am trying to get complex properties for an entity which is as follows:

Entity is from

```
typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate<EntityType>(itemCollection)
```

and I am fetching the other properties as follows:

```
var propertiesWithDefaultValues = typeMapper.GetPropertiesWithDefaultValues(entity);
var collectionNavigationProperties = typeMapper.GetCollectionNavigationProperties(entity);
var complexProperties = typeMapper.GetComplexProperties(entity);
var navigationProperties = typeMapper.GetNavigationProperties(entity);
var simpleProperties = typeMapper.GetSimpleProperties(entity);
```

So in this the complex properties should be fetched from:

```
public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetComplexProperties(EntityType type)
{
    return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is ComplexType && p.DeclaringType == type);
}
```

But none of them are being returned.

However I do get the navigation properties from:

```
public IEnumerable<NavigationProperty> GetNavigationProperties(EntityType type)
{
    return type.NavigationProperties.Where(np => np.DeclaringType == type);
}
```

But the navigation properties also contain the collection properties.

Anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe the entity does not have any complex properties?